# Driver not found

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am using SQL Server 2018 and JDK 8.0 along with NetBeans. While connecting to the SQL Server, I am getting a SQL Exception as shown in the img
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afLPG.png)

I am using the following code:

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    //Connection establishment
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver//DESKTOP-CU5U75J\\SQLSERVER1;","","");
    //Statement Object
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    //For DML use executeUpdate method of Statement Class
    st.executeUpdate("insert into Employee (Employee_Id, Employee_Name) values ("+Integer.parseInt(idTF.getText())+","+nameTF.getText()+")");
    //Commit Statement
    con.commit();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message", "The Data is Entered", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Employe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Employe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Please paste the error instead of linking to it =]

Comment: This immediate issue has been confimred fixed by adding a single colon in the connection string. As such  I'm voting to close it as "typographical error"

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:d2e6d099-51d8-46db-85e0-9ef8ae23bc71
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)

Comment: Now it is saying this. What is the problem..

Answer (score 1):

You have missed *colon* ':' in your jdbc url,

```
 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-CU5U75J\\SQLSERVER1;integratedSecurity=true","","");
```

It was `jdbc:sqlserver//DESKTOP-CU5U75J\\SQLSERVER1;` which was supposed to be `jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-CU5U75J\\SQLSERVER1;`

Also, I suggest you to use `PreparedStatement` to insert your records.

```
String sql="insert into Employee (Employee_Id, Employee_Name) values (?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(idTF.getText()));
stmt.setString(2, nameTF.getText());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Aug 11, 2018 1:07:51 AM Employe addBtnActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:2bbaf051-256f-4263-b4c4-0d9a70f04fb0
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)

Comment: Please check your user credentials information you have used for connecting to your sql server. I could see you are passing empty username and password.

Comment: Yeah because i am using the window authentication mode. So i did'nt entered any credentials. Remember that _Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-CU5U75J\\SQLSERVER1;jdbc:integratedSeurity=true","","");_ is used now.

Comment: I think the property was not set properly. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @DesignDigo Please read the documentation of the driver you are using, the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver has no property called `jdbc:integratedSecurity` (instead it is just `integratedSecurity` without a `jdbc:` prefix). And if you use integrated security, then you can just use the one argument [`getConnection(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)) method.